# Как используя Джава Скрипт создать функцию, которая из строк будет делать абривиатуры в верхнем регистре?

Tags: javascript

```
function makeAbbr(words) {
  // write code here
}
```

Comment: Чему вы научитесь, если мы будем делать домашку вместо вас?)

Answer (score 2):

Берем строку, переводим все слова в массив, пробегаемся по каждому элементу и возвращаем только первую букву в верхнем регистре.

```js
const makeAbbr = text => {
  return text.split(' ').map(i => i[0].toUpperCase()).join('.')
}
```

Comment: А точка в `join` зачем?)

Comment: Точка - это разделитель аббревиатуры, можете забрать и подставить любой символ или пробел.

Comment: В аббревиатурах нет точек, поэтому должно быть просто `join('')`. В остальном решение отличное, поставил +.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: пожалуйста, успехов

Comment: @user382492 Отметьте ответ решением